# Special character in parse

Tags: r, parsing, encoding

I want to add a greater equal sign in a text that I use in `parse`. I use `\u2265` for that.

```
parse(text = 'print("\u2265")')
```

With that and even with `encoding = "UTF-8"` this leads to `expression(print("="))`, the greater equal sign is an equal sign. What can I do to keep the greater equal sign?

Comment: Can you please show your attempt of using `encoding="UTF-8"`? Because for it works with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to double the backslash:

```
> eval(parse(text = 'print("\\u2265")'))
[1] "≥"
```

Comment: I suspect that encoding and locale are relevant in this discussion: on my console (using emacs/ess), this produces `[1] "="`. Granted, I'm (1) running emacs/ess, sometimes different; and (2) running windows, almost always different-enough to be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Due to bugs in R’s Unicode handling on Windows, it requires you to explicitly specify an encoding:

```
result = parse(text = 'print("\u2265")', encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

The result of this *looks incorrect* — for example, on my terminal it prints

> ```
> expression(print("="))
> ```

… however, this is merely a bug of the printing of the expression. The actual value is correct. You can verify this in one of two ways:

1. Extract the unevaluated expression:

   ```
   result[[1L]]
   ```

   > ```
   > print("≥")
   > ```
2. *Evaluating* the expression:

   ```
   eval(result)
   ```

   > ```
   > [1] "≥"
   > ```