# Replace backslash to double backslash in special character

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

How can I replace the backslash in `"\u2655"` (greater equal sign) to `"\\u2655"`?

I've tried the following:

```
str_replace_all("\u2265", "\\\\", "\\\\\\")
stri_replace_all_fixed("\u2265", "\\", "\\\\")
```

Both lead to `"≥"` which is not `"\u2265"`.

Comment: You can't. "\u2265" is not a string with characters \, u, 2, 2, 6, 5, it's a string with a single character ≥. Note that "\u..." is a Unicode escape.

Comment: OK ... I need this for this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018619/special-character-in-parse/68018826#68018826 The accepted answer tells me to add another backslash, but I have some `"\u2265"` stored in a variable in a dataset.

Comment: @TobiSonne So how are you reading that dataset? And what are you using `parse` for? And, lastly, which operating system are you using? Because if you’re getting `=` instead of `≥` when reading the data, there’s something very wrong and at this point it’s too late to fix it, you need to fix the code that is *originally* reading the data.

Comment: I suspect r2evans' comment to that answer is correct. But it's not clear what you really have: in my RStudio, I can't have a variable printed as "\u2265": either it's "\\u2265" (that is, it's a string with 6 characters, and it has a single \, that is escaped as \\ upon printing), or "≥".

Comment: `stri_escape_unicode` is great, you can add it as an answer, I will accept it, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Have moved comment to an answer.

Comment: OK, I think what you’re observing isn’t (only) the known, boring Unicode handling bug in R on Windows, it’s *another* (but almost certainly related) bug which messes up the printing of expressions. Interesting. [See my answer to your linked question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68020479/1968)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We interpret the problem as having an input character string containing unicode and we want to show the unicode as escaped symbols instead.

Use

```
stringi::stri_escape_unicode(x)
```

For example if `x` is a single unicode character then this will give a 6 character string whose first character is backslash, second is `u` and next 4 are digits.

```
x <- "\u2265"

nchar(x)
## [1] 1

cat(x, "\n")
## ≥

y <- stringi::stri_escape_unicode(x)

nchar(y)
## [1] 6

cat(y, "\n")
## \u2265
```